# pass a part of the array by loops via pointer to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have an array c[7][8] (or c[56]). I have to pass 8 elements of the array to a function (in a different class) for 7 times. From this function, I again have to pass this to another function. What I've tried is

```
int main(){
...
double a[]={2.1,2.2,2.3,....};//7 elements
double b[]={1.1,1.2,1.3,....};//8 elements
double c[]={0.5,0.0,0.4,....};//56 elements. I actually want to use c[7][8]; but I thought c[56] would be easier
for (int i=0; i<7; i++){
  classa.calc(a[i],b[i],&c[i*8]); //assuming I use the 1D array for c. I don't want to pass the array a and b, but ith element.
  //for c, I want to pass 8 consecutive elements of c each time i call the function like c[0-6],c[7-13] etc
}
}
```

a and b are two different arrays for which I have to use the element(i) in the function.

Now, in the class:

```
class classa{
void function(double* c, double* r) {
  ...
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) c[i]=h*c[i]*pow(x,i));//here an algorithm is used to get the new value of c as an existing function of c. the given function is just a part of the algorithm.
for (int j=0; j<N1; j++)  r[j]=some function of c;

}
public:
//here I want c to be used as a 1D array of 8 elements. same in function too
...
void calc(double a, double b, double* c){ 
  function(&c[0]);
...
}
};
```

When I run the program, I get the results for only the set of first 8 elements and a segmentation fault is given. How do I fix it?

Comment: Could you provide a complete (but minimal) example, rather than this arbitrarily cut apart example which may be missing important information.

Comment: Whenever you get a segmentation fault, or any other kind of crash, your first reaction should be to run your program in a debugger. It will help you locate the place of the crash, and also let you examine variables to see what might have caused the crash.

Comment: What Joachim said. But also: For being able to understand what is going by looking at the code it will be very important to know where `i` in `classa::function` comes from and what value it has.

Comment: I've included more details of the program; I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I would suggest you to use std::vector and it's constructor(iterator begin, iterator end) or 2D array

Answer (score 0):

### Answer as per the Update

Looks like you have more logic faults. Your loop should had run **from i=0 to 8 in function** (8 times rather than 7 times).And I also assume that *you are creating an **instance** of `classa`* otherwise create one.

```
 class classa{
    void function(double* c) {
      ...
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
        c[i]=h*c[i]*pow(x,i);    
    }
    public:
    //here I want c to be used as a 1D array of 8 elements. same in function too
    ...
    void calc(double a, double b, double* c){ 
      function(c);
    ...
    }
    };
```

### Old Answer

Since you are trying to pass &c[i][0] for seven times. This much should be enough(`assumming c is double**`).

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
   classa.calc(a[i],b[i],c[i]); //This is equal to &c[i][0] or *(c+i)
}
```

And further change `function(&c[0]);` to `function(c[0]);` because `c[0] is already double*`. [Learn Here](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch7x.htm).

```
void calc(double a, double b, double* c)
{
    function(c[0]);
    //Update with Question 
    //You are using wrong overload, it should be something like this:-> 
    function(c[0],&a);//or &b whichever applicable.
 ... 
}
```

Comment: @EugenMartynov:- Please recheck this line `56 elements. I actually want to use c[7][8];`

Comment: Eugen is correct. Also note that I am passing 8 elements of `c` for a call of `class.calc`, NOT 7. But, I have to call the function `classa.calc` 7 TIMES, thus using all the 56 elements. What I want to know is, how to pass these 56 elements as 8 elements at a time in 7 calls.

Comment: You are passing 8 elements of c,its fine.but in the loop of `function` you are iterating for seven times while wasting a cell everytime.Since you have passed 8 elements, your loop should set 8 elements and not seven :)

Comment: Right. That was just a typo. The problem is in `classa.calc(a[i],b[i],&c[i*8])` part. I can't call c[i] for classa.calc as I'm using pointers for c in classa.calc and function.

Comment: first make some instance of `classa` like `clsa` and then call `clsa.calc(a[i],b[i],(c+i*8))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually `array[n][m]` is not `array[n * m]`. You could use `a[n * m]` as replacement `b[n][m]` but with correct indexing function:

```
b[i][j] == a[i * ROW_SIZE + j];
```

Actually `&c[0] == c`, `&c[i * 8] == c + i * 8`

In your code I see two constants `7` and `N1`. could you check that `N1` is same as `7`. I assume you could go out of boundary here:

```
for (int j=0; j<N1; j++)  r[j]=some function of c;
```

Comment: N1 is not the problem. I just checked the program for single case of a[0],b[0] and c[0-8]. It was all fine. The trouble comes when I call classa.calc.